# My service randomlly close

Tags: android, android-studio, service, android-service

I made a service and when I sign in my app the services start by the following code
`Intent i= new Intent(MenuPrincipalUsuarios.this, UsuarioService.class);
        i.putExtra("idUsuario",idUsuario);
        i.putExtra("nombreUsuario",nombreUsuario);
        i.putExtra("apellidoUsuario",apellidoUsuario);
        i.putExtra("emailUsuario", emailUsuario);
        i.putExtra("telefonoUsuario",telefonoUsuario);
        startService(i);`

Everything is OK, but eventually the service die (close), I don't know why. Sometimes it's happen after 10 hours when I sign in, sometimes the service close after 15 minutes.
Why is so important to me that this service never close? Because I have a handler inside of this service that it's listening every 10 seconds if some new data appear in a table of my server.
The Service class is:

```
public class UsuarioService extends Service {

final Handler handler = new Handler();
JSONArray datosNotificacion = null;
String idCancha, anio, mes, dia, idNotificacion;
String mensaje;
String titulo;
String idOrigen;
String idUsuario;
String nombreUsuario;
String apellidoUsuario;
int diaHoy, mesHoy, anioHoy;
String emailUsuario;
String telefonoUsuario;

private static String url_fecha_actual= "http://hosting/get_dia_mes_anio_actual.php";


private static final String TAG_SUCCESSFECHA = "success";
private static final String TAG_FECHA = "fecha";
private static final String TAG_DIAHOY= "dia";
private static final String TAG_MESHOY= "mes";
private static final String TAG_ANIOHOY= "anio";
private static final String TAG_HORAREDONDEADA= "horaRedondeada";
String horaRedondeada;
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
JSONArray fecha = null;


String nombreOrigen;
//url para recibir notificacion
private static String url_notificacion = "http://hosting/get_notificacion?idUsuarioActivo=";
private static String url_delete_notificacion = "http://hosting/delete_notificacion.php?idNotificacion=";
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_DATOSNOTIFICACION = "datosNotificacion";
private static final String TAG_IDNOTIFICACION = "idNotificacion";
private static final String TAG_IDORIGEN = "idOrigen";
private static final String TAG_NOMBREORIGEN = "nombreOrigen";
private static final String TAG_TITULO = "titulo";
private static final String TAG_MENSAJE= "mensaje";
private static final String TAG_DIA = "dia";
private static final String TAG_MES = "mes";
private static final String TAG_ANIO = "anio";
private static final String TAG_IDCANCHA = "idCancha";





@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    //TODO do something useful
    idUsuario = intent.getStringExtra("idUsuario");
    nombreUsuario = intent.getStringExtra("nombreUsuario");
    apellidoUsuario = intent.getStringExtra("apellidoUsuario");
    emailUsuario = intent.getStringExtra("emailUsuario");
    telefonoUsuario = intent.getStringExtra("telefonoUsuario");
    runnable.run();
    return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;

}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

    //TODO for communication return IBinder implementation
    return null;
}

//Runnable para generar la accion de buscar notificacion cada X minutos
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        if(isConnectingToInternet(getApplicationContext())){
            new BuscarNotificaciones().execute();
        }
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 10000);
    }
};

private boolean isConnectingToInternet(Context applicationContext){
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo ni = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (ni == null) {
        // There are no active network
        return false;
    } else
        return true;
}


class BuscarNotificaciones extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Obtenemos el string del JSON desde la URL
        JSONObject json2 = null;
        try {

            json2 = JSONParser.readJsonFromUrl(url_notificacion.concat(idUsuario));
        } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            // Verifica que se cargaron datos
            //assert json2 != null;
            int success;// = json2.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            if(json2 == null){
                success = 0;
            }
            else {
                success = json2.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            }
            if (success == 1) {
                Random random = new Random();
                int m = random.nextInt(9999 - 1000) + 1000;

                datosNotificacion= json2.getJSONArray(TAG_DATOSNOTIFICACION);

                JSONObject c2 = datosNotificacion.getJSONObject(0);
                idNotificacion = c2.getString(TAG_IDNOTIFICACION);
                idOrigen = c2.getString(TAG_IDORIGEN);
                nombreOrigen = c2.getString(TAG_NOMBREORIGEN);
                titulo = c2.getString(TAG_TITULO);
                mensaje= c2.getString(TAG_MENSAJE);
                dia= c2.getString(TAG_DIA);
                mes= c2.getString(TAG_MES);
                anio= c2.getString(TAG_ANIO);
                idCancha= c2.getString(TAG_IDCANCHA);
                //uri donde esta el sonido por defecto de la notificacion
                Uri uri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
                Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.notification_icon_large);

                Intent intent = new Intent(UsuarioService.this, CalcularHorariosDisponibles.class);
                intent.putExtra("idComplejo",idOrigen);
                intent.putExtra("idUsuario", idUsuario);
                intent.putExtra("idCancha",idCancha);
                intent.putExtra("dia",dia);
                intent.putExtra("mes",mes);
                intent.putExtra("anio",anio);
                intent.putExtra("nombreUsuario", nombreUsuario);
                intent.putExtra("apellidoUsuario", apellidoUsuario);
                intent.putExtra("diaHoy", String.valueOf(diaHoy));
                intent.putExtra("horaRedondeada", horaRedondeada);

                PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                        PendingIntent.getActivity(
                                UsuarioService.this,
                                m,
                                intent,
                                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                        );//creamos la notificacion
                NotificationCompat.Builder n  = new NotificationCompat.Builder(UsuarioService.this)
                        .setContentTitle(titulo)
                        .setSound(uri)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
                        .setLargeIcon(bm)
                        .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
                        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText("El complejo " + nombreOrigen + " " + mensaje))
                        .setAutoCancel(true);
                NotificationManager notificationManager =
                        (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                notificationManager.notify(m, n.build());
                //eliminamos la notificacion para que no se sigan generando las notificaciones
                JSONObject json3 = null;
                try {
                    json3 = JSONParser.readJsonFromUrl(url_delete_notificacion.concat(idNotificacion));
                } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {}
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
    super.onDestroy();
}
}
```

If the service close, user dont receive the notification and it cant happen.

My AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity
        android:name=".MenuPrincipalUsuarios"
        android:label="¡Bienvenido!"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Dark" />

<service
        android:name="com.sourcey.modeloUsuarios.UsuarioService"
        android:icon="@drawable/notification_icon"
        android:label="Servicio"
        >
</service>
```

Also, users told me that the app sign out randomlly. It is happen in some phones. I don't know if this is related with the first problem. But if the app sign out alone they never gonna get the notification. And that's is a problem too.

Thanks for everything!
Thanks!

Comment: Assuming you're aren't crashing-  the Android system frequently kills background services for resources.  Make sure to return START_STICKY from onStartCommand so it will restart it when resources are available again.

Comment: Also if you're polling every 10 seconds-  don't do that.  Its highly inefficient, and you aren't letting your CPU go to sleep meaning you'll kill battery.  Back it off to every few minutes, or better yet implement push messaging from the server.

Comment: Well, I tried it and didn't work. May be because the service has to start with some parameters. But if i kill the app with START_STICKY the services not restart

Comment: I tried to use GCM but you have to register and it's too dificult. May be you have a easy form to implement push messaing from the server